# drop down menu displaying behind content

Tags: html, css

```
.login_nav{
display: block;
font-family: arial;
}

.login_nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

.login_nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.login_nav ul {
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
float:right;
width: 65%;
}

.login_nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

.login_nav ul li {
padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(30,30,30,0.4);
}
.login_nav ul li:hover {
    background: rgba(30,30,30,0.4);
}
    .login_nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

.login_nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #e1e1e1; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.login_nav ul ul {
background: rgba(30,30,30,0.6); 
border-radius: 0px; 
padding: 0;
width: 200px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 5000;
left: 100%; 
top:0;
}
.login_nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}
    .login_nav ul ul li a {
        color: #e1e1e1;
    }
```

Heres the css for my drop down menu. The problem is that the drop down menu is appearing behind my content. I have tried playing around with `z-index` and `overflow` but I cant seem to get it working or maybe im just not putting it the right place. Im sure it is something simple and I just havnt seen it.

I have the `z-index` of my content container set to `1`

Comment: try giving z-index value in -ve(negative value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the z-index in .login_nav and give it a value of 1000. I had the same problem with my nav bar